# Does Google encrypt data in their Datastore indexes on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

With GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) going into effect tomorrow, I am wondering whether Google encrypts data in their Datastore indexes on GAE. I know that they encrypt data stored in entities but it isn't clear that they encrypt the data in indexes. I can't imagine that this is even possible given that queries would never be able to run on encrypted data. If the indexed data is not encrypted, would this not be considered to make GAE non-compliant with GDPR?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All data in Cloud Datastore is encrypted at rest as documented at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/encryption-at-rest .

Comment: At rest but NOT in indexes. You cannot run queries on indexes when the data is encrypted. So no, it is not. Only in the datastore that is not part of indexes.

Comment: Even the indexes are encrypted at rest.  You are correct, that the metadata & data needs to be decrypted to run the queries, but that doesn't prevent the indexes being encrypted at rest.

Comment: How do you know that? Do you work for Google and have first hand knowledge? I can hardly imagine that GAE is going to encrypt a massive amount of index data at rest just to decrypt it while running a query - especially queries where you have a lot of users and the query executes a massive number of times throughout the day. There is nothing in the documentation that address this, so unless you work (or worked for) Google, you're just making a guess.

Comment: Disclosure, I work on Cloud Datastore.  That said, a previous system I worked on is documented at https://www.quantcast.com/blog/keebler-design-for-simplicity-and-scale/ .  If you look at the "On Disk Format", you'll notice that the index file can easily be encrypted since it is read all at once, and as long as the data sections are encrypted independently then it's easy to have encryption at rest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably certain they don't actually. The [HIPAA compliance guide](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/#customer_responsibilities) specifically instructs you to encrypt PHI before using it as an index key. Here's the full text:

> When creating or configuring indexes in Google Cloud Datastore, encrypt any PHI, security credentials, or other sensitive data, before using it as the entity key, indexed property key, or indexed property value for the index. See the Cloud Datastore documentation for information on creating and/or configuring indexes.

I'm assuming this means you need to do your own encryption here, otherwise I'm not sure why they'd mention it. And no, I don't know how a meaningful database index can be built from encrypted data.

Comment: Note that this caveat does not apply to Cloud Firestore in either mode.

Answer (score 0):

Google encrypts and authenticates all data in transit at one or more network layers when data moves outside physical boundaries not controlled by Google, it also has 7 layer type of data encryption. More information about Encryption in Transit can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit/). There's also the [Server-Side Encryption](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/encryption-at-rest) in Datastore.

Comment: I wasn't interested in "transit". The question is about data at rest, meaning as it is stored on their hard drives. I don't believe Google is obligated by GDPR to encrypt data on their servers. Only in transit.

Comment: The server-side encryption link that I pasted in my answer deals with encryption at rest (check the URL of the webpage). Also: "Google Cloud Platform encrypts customer data stored at rest by default, with no additional action required from you." (source [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/)).